# Amazon Textract Start document analysis - messages from SQS are all empty,

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-textract

Hi I am developing an application in Java that parses documents using AWS Textract. For multipage parse I use the startDocumentAnalysis method available on the textract client. This client then responds with a jobId and the jobId is placed on the sqs queue along with it's completion status. I had a personal account previously and managed to get all of it working so a process reads messages from the queue and then get the result of the parse using :

```java
GetDocumentAnalysisRequest documentAnalysisRequest = GetDocumentAnalysisRequest.builder().jobId(jobId)
                    .maxResults(maxResults).nextToken(paginationToken).build();
```

Now i have to do that on my company's AWS account and i have retraced my steps and everything works except now when i go to pick up the messages from the queue, all the messages come back as [] i.e. empty array.
I use this code:

```java
messages = sqsClient.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).messages();
```

So i know the error can't be in the java code because previously it worked.
I also know that i can upload to the new bucket and also do single page parses, so i know my credentials are correct.
I have created a topic on sns and registered my sqs to it but somewhere here there must be a permission or other configuration error. Maybe SNS and SQS are not talking to each other?

Wonder if anyone has any insights that could help me.
Thank you

Comment: Does your new IAM role you are using have a policy to use SQS?  You are correct - if your Java worked with the other account - your Java logic is not the issue.

Comment: I started with an I AM user with these permissions: AmazonTextractFullAccess

AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess

AmazonSNSFullAccess

AmazonSQSFullAccess but could not upload to bucket, so now i'm trying with an IAM user with admin role but i am now gonna go back to the first role and find a way to add S3 read and write if there's such a thing.

Comment: Ok i tested with the first account and i could not upload to the bucket as previously so i added the user to the administrators group as well as the ones above and I am back at the scenario that all messages are empty. Sounds like sns and sqs are not talking to each other.

Comment: Figured it out. It was all in this point from the documentation. Prepend name with AmazonTextraxt! 
        "Create an Amazon SNS topic. Prepend the topic name with AmazonTextract. Note the topic Amazon Resource Name (ARN). Ensure that the topic is in the same Region as the AWS endpoint that you're using."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. It's all to do with the naming convention of the SNS topic. Explained in the documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/api-async-roles.html

Step3 - Create an Amazon SNS topic. Prepend the topic name with AmazonTextract. Note the topic Amazon Resource Name (ARN). Ensure that the topic is in the same Region as the AWS endpoint that you're using.